# Cannot retrieve correct checkbox value after it is clicked with jQuery

Tags: jquery, checkbox, jquery-events

I have a checkbox. I have assigned a click-event to the checkbox. In the method that is called I want to see if the checkbox is checked or not. The expected result is that if the checkbox is not checked and I click it, in the method the checked value should be "true" and vice versa. I can't get this result with my code. I always get "false" as checked. How can I solve this?

Am I using the wrong event?
I use jQuery 1.8.2

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".UpdateCheckboxInstant").change(UpdateInstant);
});
    
function UpdateInstant() {
  //var checked = $(".UpdateCheckboxInstant").is(":checked");
  var checked = $(this).is(":checked");
  alert(checked); // this always says "false" :(
}
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant markup?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/LaFmQ/) on jsFiddle. I think it actually works for me.

```
<input type="checkbox" class="UpdateCheckboxInstant" />​

$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".UpdateCheckboxInstant").change(UpdateInstant);
});
function UpdateInstant() {
  //var checked = $(".UpdateCheckboxInstant").is(":checked");
  var checked = $(this).is(":checked");
  alert(checked);
}
​
```

Comment: Probably a typo in his HTML code. This happens to me sometimes as well.

Comment: Thanks guys, sorry I should have posted the markup. I use an asp:checkbox..when I changed to input-checkbox it worked fine. I don't know what the difference is between them in the resulting source on the client so if someone can explain that to a relatively noob html developer I would appreciate it. :)

Comment: I am guessing that it probably has something to do with you ID attribute. For ASP.NET control, to get correct client ID, you should call `Control.ClientID` property. If you can pass that ID value into your JS and you should then be able to get the right reference.